# How to save the matrix displayed on console as an Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to get the statistics from a data frame, but I do not know how to export them from Console.

For example, I have a data frame, let us say that is called "df", then I obtained the statistics by the function of .describe(). The results displayed on Console. But I have no idea how to save the matrix displayed on Console as an excel file.

```
print(df.describe(include=["object"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use another df to store the describe()

```
new_df = df.describe()
new_df.to_excel("df_describe.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work in one line:

`df.describe(include=["object"]).to_excel('path/to/file.xlsx')`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html